# Adding custom web part to page: not registered as safe

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have created a feature that contains 4 web parts.  The feature is working great on my dev environment so I am trying to move it over to production.  I added and deployed the feature without incident and 2 of the 4 web parts can be added to pages fine.  The other 2 produce the following error:

Unable to add selected web part(s).
(Web Part Name): A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported.  The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

The web parts are fairly similar, they contain textboxes, dropdowns, and peopleeditors, nothing special. All 4 show up in the web part gallery.  I have the following entry in my web.config:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="xxx_WebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=274c568f7ef9ca81" Namespace="xxx_WebPart.UI.WebControls.WebParts" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

I've been searching on the error but most hits seem to point to the web.config entry which I have.  I'm stumped as to why 2 of the 4 web parts are working and the others aren't.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the two that are failing using some other control or library? Any UI control referenced and rendered has to be added to the safe controls. If you're using a 3rd party DLL that wasn't packaged properly or is using controls not marked as safe then you'll see this issue.

Try looking at the webpart XML as well and make sure you're referencing the right DLLs (this can get out of sync if you refactor class/namespace but don't edit the webpart to match). In this case your webpart would still show in the gallery (it's just XML after all; no problem there) but trying to use it would throw this error due to the webpart trying to reference a DLL that wasn't registered (and likely doesn't exist). If this is the trouble you should deactivate the feature, ensure the webpart is deleted from the gallery then deploy your changes and reactivate. You can view the webpart XML from the browser to see that it's been updated/corrected.

Comment: Ah, this may have been it.  I had checked the web part XML but I guess I didn't look closely enough.  I changed the names of my code files at some point and it was still referencing the old names inside the web part XML.  I just redeployed and although it still isn't working I'm guessing I may need an iisreset which I can't do at the moment.  Many thanks!

Comment: Your webpart is likely still in the gallery unless you had some Feature_Decativated code that removed it. In this case your broken webparts weren't updated. Just go into the gallery and delete them and re-activate the feature. Or view their XML to see if they weren't updated correctly. I'm not in front of my dev station at the moment but there is another place the dll is listed in string format (thus not seen in a refactor action) in either feature.xml or elements.xml if a feature receiver was used, I believe. Give those a look as well.

Comment: That was it, once I removed them and reactivated the feature it was good to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue, but my solution was a little different. I had refactored the namespace before working on the web part, but didn't update any of the configuration. As mentioned in the other answer above I updated the WebPart XML file, but that didn't do the trick.

There's a property on the WebPart called **Safe Control Entries** as pictured below:

[image: Safe Control Entries detail]

You'll have to edit the Safe Control Entries collection and update the namespace in the first entry. After you update that, Sharepoint shouldn't complain anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else arriving here in the future...

If everything looks correct and you've got everything in place already but it's still not working, try un-registering the DLL from the GAC with "gacutil -u assemblyname" and redeploying your solution.

I wasted so many hours on that and I'd even copied the DLL from the GAC and checked with DotPeek that my webpart class was in there!

Obviously something was wrong and doing this fixed it.  Hope this helps someone else.